# Docker installation on Mac m1

Tags: docker, macos, apple-m1

I am trying to install Docker desktop on Mac m1 but after installation dockers asks to execute following command.

docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started

But, it gives following error

Unable to find image 'docker/getting-started:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": read tcp 192.168.65.4:58764->192.168.65.5:3128: read: connection reset by peer.
See 'docker run --help'.

Why is it not pulling docker data?

Answer (score -1):

(Sorry for the miss... going to try this again)

Try `docker exec` command before your command.

Like this `docker exec docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started`

"Tried using the docker exec command and it appears to have worked OK with two different ubuntu instances. Did not try Docker Desktop.
It kind of looks like there is a problem with Docker Desktop manipulating Terminal.app.
I’m using the macOS default zshell."

https://forums.docker.com/t/problems-getting-started/116487/9

Comment: The question doesn't include a `docker run -v` option or any environment variable expansions at all.

Comment: I tried above command it returns following error 
Error: No such container: docker